# MSBuild - Custom assembly version format

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, versioning

Is there any way to use a custom format for assembly versions, when building them with MSBuild?

For example, we tried to use a version like "0.16.10r2.10717" But we got this error:

`error emitting 'system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute' -- The version specified '0.16.10r2.10717' is invalid.`

I searched around the web, but seems no one asked for a solution of this. Is it possible?

We use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and FinalBuilder 7 for building our project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[AssemblyVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [AssemblyFileVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) both must be composed of up to four integers, period-separated, each of which is no larger than 65534 (`UInt16.MaxValue-1`). Any of the following are valid (C# syntax):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]

// Let the compiler generate the build and/or revision numbers
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]
```

There is another attribute, [AssemblyInformationalVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), that accepts a string as the version; it can be used when you want to use more complicated strings (especially when including a commit ID from a DVCS).

```
// Use complex version number
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.16.10r2.10717")]

// Include Git commit ID
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.2b1-g39d1c0f")]
```

Briefly, the [difference between these attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z.aspx) is:

- **AssemblyVersion**: This is used as the CLR version of the assembly. When the assembly has a strong-name, this is the version that is validated against.
- **AssemblyFileVersion**: This is the Win32 file version resource, and is displayed in the assembly's properties in Windows Explorer.
- **AssemblyInformationalVersion**: This is accessible at runtime via the `Application.ProductVersion` property. It is also used in the `Application.UserAppDataDirectory` path.